# Масштабирование сайта при изменении размеров окна браузера

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так чтобы при изменении размеров окна браузера, пропорционально уменьшать элементы?
Как будто все единая картинка, и картинка пропорционально уменьшается.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: Способов много разных для разных задач, для более полезного ответа лучше расскажите, зачем вам это надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

или верстать изначально ориентируясь на ширину экрана (задавая ВСЕ размеры в `vw`), или отключить все параметры вьюпорта в хеде, сверстать под фулл хд разрешение, а потом  скриптом брать ширину экрана и делать `transform:scale(calc(%device width% / 1920))` всему `body`. Ну, заодно добавить `transform:translate(...)`, чтобы показывало с самого начала экрана и `overflow:hidden` для `<html>`, чтобы скроллбаров не было. как-то так =)))

Answer (score 2):

Странно зачем вам такое? Если я правильно понимаю, вы хотите чтоб как оно выглядит на десктопе, так же оно должно выглядит на телефоне?

Просто не добавлять в тег `<head>` этот параметр, либо если он есть то удалить:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Точно не уверен.